# change #DIV/0! into a zero

Tags: excel

I trying to understand, how to change a cell answer from #DIV/0! to O. The basic formula `=AC298/P298`gives  the standard message (#DIV/0!). I am trying to find a percentage of "admissions" that have been "referred to community partners". Cell C298 shows the sum number of admissions in the month of October. Cell AC298 shows the number of people who have been referred to community partners during the month of October. I have tried `=IF(AC298,P298/P298,0)`.  I am wondering if this is the correct formula or is there a better way of doing this.

Comment: Your way would work, but you need to check the denominator -- You would want `=IF(P298<>0,AC298/P298,0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write `=IFERROR(AC298/P298, 0)`.

If the first argument to `IFERROR` is an error type, then 0 is substituted.

Although it might be better to write `=IF(P298 = 0, 0, AC298/P298)` in case an error emanates from somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for providing a better solution & explaining why.